# malloc error when switching to objective-c++ in xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, malloc, type-conversion, objective-c++

I have a C++ class that I would like to use in my Objective-C project. Without #including any C++ headers, when I rename my Obj-C files from ".m" to ".mm", and thus switch the compiler, the compiler produces a whole bunch of malloc errors:

```
double * pointValues = malloc(sizeof(double *)*numOfPts);

error: invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'double*'
```

Suddenly all lines with malloc become invalid.
Do I have to typecast "malloc" when using the Obj-C++ compiler, or is this a manifestation of some other issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C++, there is no implicit conversion from `void*` to other pointer types, so you have to explicitly cast.
Not only with the objective-C++ compiler.

Comment: Thanks, I had no idea since I've been using the "new" and "delete" methods in C++ thus far.

Answer (score 0):

C++ has strong typing. The direct conversion is not allowed in C++:

```
double * pointValues = (double*) malloc(sizeof(double *)*numOfPts);
//                        |
//                  explicit cast
```